# How to handle Firebase password reset email errors Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am making a simple password reset dialog that will send a password reset email to the user via firebase. Everything works fine, however, I want to be able to catch and handle errors accordingly. I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing this. For example, when the user's internet connection cuts out, I want them to see a message that their password reset email was not sent via a snackbar.

My Code:

```
// Send user an email for password reset
Future<void> _resetPassword(String email) async {
  await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
}

// This will handle the password reset dialog for login_password
void passwordResetDialog(context, email) {
  displayDialog(
    context,
    title: "Forgot Password?",
    content:
        "We will send you an email with a password reset link. Press on that link and follow the instructions from there.",
    leftOption: "No",
    onPressedLeftOption: () {
      // Close dialog
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
    rightOption: "Yes",
    onPressedRightOption: () {
      
      // Send reset password email
      _resetPassword(email);

      // Close dialog
      Navigator.of(context).pop();

      displaySnackBar(
        context,
        contentText: "Password reset email sent",
        durationTime: 7,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
try {
 await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
 print(e.code);
 print(e.message);
// show the snackbar here
}
```

Read more [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have implemented this. However, it does not seem to provide an error if the user does not have an internet connection. Is there any way to address that?

Answer (score 0):

İt can be late answer but;

With the [documentation][1]

[1]: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/sendPasswordResetEmail.html help, you can catch some use cases,
like invalid-continue-uri, missing-ios-bundle-id and etc.

```
on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
 switch(e.code){
   case "missing-ios-bundle-id":
     //do some work
   default:
     ///Show snackbar, navigate user to different page, etc.
}
```

And also I am highly recomended to create an extension on FirebaseAuthException and with that you can create one of manager function like;

```
CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes get coreCreateOperationExceptionType {
switch (code) {
  case "email-already-in-use":
    return CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes.createUserEmailAlreadyInUse;
  case "invalid-email":
    return CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes.createUserInvalidEmail;
  case "operation-not-allowed":
    return CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes.createUserOperationNotAllowed;
  case "weak-password":
    return CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes.createUserWeakPassword;
  default:
    return CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes.createUserUnknownError;
}
```

with this way(CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes(rename your own error enum)),  you can write exception on RenamedYourAuthExceptionTypes and with help of that enum you can simply use useful getters like; CoreFirebaseAuthExceptionTypes.type.snackBarMessage,